# bash: make the grep command to ignore line with certain special characters $(

Tags: bash, grep

Hi I am trying to make the grep ignore line with certain special characters $(

Input:

```
/XGenerator.mk:98:LOCAL_MODULE := filesxml.sh
/XGenerator.mk:106:LOCAL_MODULE := doublefiles.sh
/LibParameter.mk:35:LOCAL_MODULE := libparameter$(SUFFIX)
/LibUtility.mk:35:LOCAL_MODULE := libpfw_utility$(SUFFIX)
```

Expected output:

```
/XGenerator.mk:98:LOCAL_MODULE := filesxml.sh
/XGenerator.mk:106:LOCAL_MODULE := doublefiles.sh
```

My try1

```
grep -Rin "LOCAL_MODULE :=" --include="*.mk" | grep -v '$('
```

not working

My try2

```
grep -Rin "LOCAL_MODULE :=" --include="*.mk" | grep -v '/$/('
```

not working

Please can anyone help ?

Comment: `not working` what does it mean "now working"? "Not working" in what way? Can you be more specific?

Comment: I mentioned both are not working. In the sense it doesnt produce the desired output

Comment: What do they produce? Any other output? [it works for me repl link](https://repl.it/@kamilcukrowski/SnappyDrearyDaemons#main.sh). The "input:" part is the output of the first `grep -Rin`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a logic OR in your grep command

```
grep -Rin "LOCAL_MODULE :=" --include="*.mk" | grep -v '\$\|('
```

Explanation:
The -v flag exclude line matching the pattern, as you already know. The $ character need to be escaped, as well as the OR special character |.